# Persist Data even if app is cleared

Tags: java, android, database, sharedpreferences, persistent-storage

I need to save a device id locally and it should be saved even if user clears the app data,how can i do this?
Storing it in db or preferences is not going to work as it would be cleared.

I am using firebase in the app and as such it generates a device id which i save in an online db.Whenever the app data clears firebase generates a new ID for the device which i want to update for this specific device but i can't do that because i lose the previous ID using which i could have uniquely identified the row to update in my online db.
Is there any way i can store the previous ID even if the app data is cleared?

Comment: You could export the data to a text file on the storage.

Comment: In general, that is not possible, to prevent developers from leaving all sorts of crap behind when their apps are uninstalled.

Comment: @Commonsware So, you mean that I can't take a screenshot and save it to the gallery or write a text file on the SD card?

Comment: @Rotwang: The question implies that the user should not be able to delete the device ID. If the data is on external or removable storage, the user can delete it. If the data is on internal storage, it will be cleared when the user uninstalls the app or clears the app's data through Settings. I am not aware of any place where a developer can store data that the user cannot delete, to prevent developers from leaving all sorts of crap behind when their apps are uninstalled.

Comment: @Commonsware I must have overlooked the question. I thought the OP asked if he could save the data somewhere in order to restore it upon a reinstallation. So, not to loose all the (say) game scores or whatever data the app is all about. Of course the user could voluntarily delete the data (and must be free to), even if - by doing so - the next app run wouldn't be able to restore the data.

Comment: I added a little more information.